# Can anyone clarify this whole jQuery method?

Tags: jquery

What's the purpose of this line of jQuery? I know what .scrollTop() does, but documentation claims it cannot be passed arguments --- > http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/. I takes the pixels scrolled from top and then the scrollHeight property as an argument, I don't get the idea behind it.

```
$("#container").scrollTop($("#container").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

Comment: Look here ... scrollTop can have an argument http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop2

Comment: You need to scroll down to the page you linked to further and read how scrollTop() can set the vertical position as well.

Comment: There's something about the jQuery documentation that's not entirely easy to spot all its contents. Maybe it's just the way they format their docs, but it has happened to me before that I just don't realize all the possible function calls. OP, many jQuery docs will present this same format, they'll cover no-argument calls as if they were getters and calls with a value te be set, like setters. In different sections.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `scrollTop` to value of `scrollHeight` will result in the page scrolling down the height of the entire page, i.e. this will scroll a webpage page down to the very bottom.

Comment: So, instead of just stopping at the bottom of, say, a div, it'll continue down to the page bottom, right?

Comment: Yes, as if the vertical scroll bar had been pulled down as far as it would go.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd entry for scrollTop docs say it does take an integer value - where the scroll to. So, this bit of code grabs the value of the "scrollHeight" property from the element at ID=container and telling #container to scroll to that value.